# Python statements not executing sequentially?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following three lists:

```
d1 = [{"Names": ["Chris","Sam","Max"], "Color": "Blue"},{"Names": ["Albert","Robert","Julie"], "Color": "Red"}] 
d2 = [{"SomeNames": ["April","John","Erin"], "Color": "Green"},{"SomeNames": ["Phillip","Nate","Wendy"], "Color": "Yellow"}]
d3 = [{"Color": "Pink"}, {"Color": "Purple"}, {"Color": "Orange"}]
```

If I run the code:

```
for item in d2:
    item["Names"]=item.pop("SomeNames")
    d1.append(item)

print(d1)
```

I get:

```
[{'Names': ['Chris', 'Sam', 'Max'], 'Color': 'Blue'}, {'Names': ['Albert', 'Robert', 'Julie'], 'Color': 'Red'}, {'Names': ['April', 'John', 'Erin'], 'Color': 'Green'}, {'Names': ['Phillip', 'Nate', 'Wendy'], 'Color': 'Yellow'}]
```

If I run the code:

```
for item in d2:
    item.pop("SomeNames")
    d3.append(item)
```

I get:

```
[{'Color': 'Pink'}, {'Color': 'Purple'}, {'Color': 'Orange'}, {'Color': 'Green'}, {'Color': 'Yellow'}]
```

So far so good.  However, if I try to combine them into the same loop:

```
for item in d2:

    item["Names"]=item.pop("SomeNames")
    d1.append(item)

    item.pop("Names")
    d3.append(item)

print(d1)
print(d3)
```

I get:

```
[{'Names': ['Chris', 'Sam', 'Max'], 'Color': 'Blue'}, {'Names': ['Albert', 'Robert', 'Julie'], 'Color': 'Red'}, {'Color': 'Green'}, {'Color': 'Yellow'}]
[{'Color': 'Pink'}, {'Color': 'Purple'}, {'Color': 'Orange'}, {'Color': 'Green'}, {'Color': 'Yellow'}]
```

Which means somehow when I do both commands right after one another I lose the following list items:

```
{'Names': ['April', 'John', 'Erin']}
{'Names': ['Phillip', 'Nate', 'Wendy']}
```

I was **expecting** to get:

```
[{'Names': ['Chris', 'Sam', 'Max'], 'Color': 'Blue'}, {'Names': ['Albert', 'Robert', 'Julie'], 'Color': 'Red'}, {'Names': ['April', 'John', 'Erin'], 'Color': 'Green'}, {'Names': ['Phillip', 'Nate', 'Wendy'], 'Color': 'Yellow'}]
[{'Color': 'Pink'}, {'Color': 'Purple'}, {'Color': 'Orange'}, {'Color': 'Green'}, {'Color': 'Yellow'}]
```

Shouldn't those pop commands execute sequentially in the loop?  I don't understand why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: You're appending the same item to each of d1 and d3. It's not a copy, it's the same object. If you modify it, then it's modified, it doesn't matter how you access it, you'll see the results of that modification. - if you also print d2 at the end, you'll see that the objects in it look exactly like those that you've added to d1 and d3. You can even then get them from d2 again, and modify them again - you'll see those changes if you print d1 and d3 again.

Comment: Could you suggest a way to accomplish what I am trying within the same loop?  As a beginner I'd really appreciate the suggestions.  :)

Comment: I assume that there's a way to produce a copy of `item`. I would do that and then mutate and add that to d1, then a separate copy to mutate and add to d3. I don't actually use python, so I don't know how, - someone who actually uses python may come along and answer, or perhaps if you search for how to copy a python dictionary (I *think* they're dictionaries - again: I don't use python) you might find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @moreON is correct, if you want to reuse a dict, but change it in one place, you have to clone it or create a new one.

create a new dict version:

```
for item in d2:
    item["Names"] = item.pop("SomeNames")
    d1.append(item)

    d3.append({'Color': item['Color']})
```

copy dict version:

```
for item in d2:
    item["Names"] = item.pop("SomeNames")
    d1.append(item)

    new_item = dict(item)
    new_item.pop('Names')
    d3.append(new_item)
```

Haven't figure out a better way yet.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative way to do this:

```
for dic in d2:
    d1.append({k.replace('SomeNames', 'Names'):v for k,v in dic.items()})
    d3.append({'Color': dic['Color']})
```